# JavaFx Node Relocation

Tags: javafx, translate, bounds, boundary

I have this piece of code that relocates a ball after it passes a certain boundary.  The problem is that it only does this once.  It is supposed to do this every time.  What am I doing wrong?

```
if (circle.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY() > bg.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY()) {
    circle.relocate(100, 100);
}
```

I move the ball like this:

```
    circle.setTranslateX(circle.getTranslateX() + deltaX);
    circle.setTranslateY(circle.getTranslateY() + deltaY);
```

Comment: How is the ball moving?

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation of the [relocate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#relocate-double-double-) method:

> Sets the node's layoutX and layoutY translation properties in order to
>   relocate this node to the x,y location in the parent.
>
> This method does not alter translateX or translateY, which if also set
>   will be added to layoutX and layoutY, adjusting the final location by
>   corresponding amounts.

Since you didn't provide much to work with, my guess is you shouldn't use relocate and instead use setTranslateX and setTranslateY.

Comment: Id like for it to relocate back to a specific coordinate.  SetTranslate is relative.  Relocate works the first time but not the second, its very confusing.

Comment: But if you relocate, then the translate coordinates are still applied as well unless you explicitly set them back to 0.

Comment: How would I explicitly set the coordinates back to 0?

Comment: setTranslateX(0) and setTranslateY(0).

Comment: Then please set this answer to "accepted" before other volunteers spend their spare time reading this answered question.